# In R, how to do rowsums for columns with negative and positive integers?

Tags: r, rowsum

I'm trying to sum 4 columns, some of which have negative values.
I get an error message when I do so:

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Is there a way to overcome this and get the sum? I read what's been written about the error showing up but couldn't figure out a solution

Here is my code:

```
calculation1 <- (rawdata$Concat1 * 12 / rawdata$Size) 
calculation2 <- rawdata$Concat2 * 12 / rawdata$Size
calculation3 <- rawdata$Concat3 * 12 / rawdata$Size
calculation4 <- rawdata$Concat4 * 12 / rawdata$Size

rawdata$Cost <- rowSums(rawdata[,c(calculation1, calculation2, calculation3, 
calculation4)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects 'calculation' are not column names.  We can get those objects in to a `list` with `mget`, `cbind` and do the `rowSums`

```
rawdata$Cost <- rowSums(do.call(cbind,
       mget(ls(pattern = '^calculation\\d+$'))), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or use `cbind` instead of `c` to convert to a `matrix` (or `data.frame`)

```
rowSums(cbind(calculation1, calculation2, calculation3,  
       calculation4), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Also, instead of creating multiple objects, we could do this simply by

```
rowSums(rawdata[paste0('Concat', 1:4)] * 12/rawdata$Size, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks @akrun this worked! But how would I add this as a column in my dataframe? (rawdata)

Comment: @Pre just assign it to `rawdata$Cost <- rowSums(do.call(cbind,
       mget(ls(pattern = '^calculation\\d+$'))), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I did this: rawdata$Cost <- rowSums(cbind(calculation1, calculation2, calculation3,  
              calculation4), na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: @Pre My first option is when you have more than 10 objects created (not recommended to create objecst like that)

Comment: yes that's true - this was a quick method and I changed the column names in the example: they are in the form Xconcat (where X is a different string for each column)